# Powershell script to handle multi line data in excel cell and convert to csv using Import-excel or Import-csv

Tags: excel, powershell, import-from-excel, import-csv, export-csv

Q: I want to convert excel to csv but the excel contains multiline data in a cell along with ";" as delimiter. The desired output is a csv file with "|" as separator for columns but "," as separator for data within same cell. I cannot use excel hence I am using the module "ImportExcel".

Input Excel Format (attached file at end of Question) :-

```
Row1# c1# c2#                    c3#         c4#
Row2#
Row3#
Row4#     HEADER1                HEADER2     HEADER3
Row5#     04.05 test &amp; t     test        TEST
Row5#     04.06.01 test test                 TEST
Row5#     04.07.01 test test 
Row5#     04.10.02 test &amp; t
```

Row# represents the row of the excel and c# represent the column while HEADER# represent the title of the columns. As can be seen, ROW 1-3 and first column of the excel are empty. The text of second and fourth column is multiline but in the same cell(same row Row5).

I tried to Import the excel then for each object and replace the new line character with "," finally export it to csv using(export-csv) with "|" as delimiter.

The script I made is as follows :-

```
$test = Import-excel -NoHeader -StartRow(4) test.xlsx

$test | foreach-object {

if($_.HEADER1) {
$_.HEADER1 = $_.HEADER1.replace("\n",", ")
$_.HEADER1 = $_.HEADER1.replace("&amp;","& ")
   }
}

$test | Export-csv new-test.csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output CSV FILE I GET :-

```
Row1# c1# c2#                       c3#
Row2#     HEADER1|HEADER2|HEADER3
Row3#     04.05 test &amp            t
Row4#     04.06.01 test test          
Row5#     04.07.01 test test 
Row6#     04.10.02 test &amp         t
Row7#     test|TEST
Row8#     TEST
```

As can be seen, the text after the delimeter ";" in the input goes to another column and the multiline is still parsed into separate rows. I want all this multiline to be merged into one with "," as separator along with the text after the "';" delimeter.

Desired CSV FILE :-

```
Row1# c1# c2#                
Row2#     HEADER1|HEADER2|HEADER3
Row3#     04.05 test &  t,04.06.01 test test,04.07.01 test test,04.10.02 test & t|test|TEST,TEST
```

I have tried a lot of questions from stackoverflow related to this but for some reason none of the existing solution seems to be working for me.

Attached is the sample Excel file I am trying to convert. [**test.xlsx**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12jupQ2dJcVrja_ACkSjZV2RwBoHbnyE0/view?fbclid=IwAR2AeQq25bXveMrNKIHj-k1yubeAUQWTdFACRxfUuXCCXj_0zAJb_R7MX60)

Comment: Please provide the [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as we don't have access to test.xlsx. Perhaps grab some example lines and place them in an array ```$test = @('line1', 'line2')```

Comment: @lloyd .. Thanks for the reply. I have attached the document to the question at the end. Hope this helps but let me know if more information or example is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you specify the `-NoHeader` parameter.
and you have to specify `` `n `` instead of `\n` as a newline character in `Replace()` method.

```
$test = Import-Excel test.xlsx -StartRow 4
$test | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.HEADER1) {
        $_.HEADER1 = $_.HEADER1.Replace("`n", ", ")
        $_.HEADER1 = $_.HEADER1.Replace("&amp;", "&")
    }
    if($_.HEADER3) {
        $_.HEADER3 = $_.HEADER3.Replace("`n", ", ")
    }
}

$test | Export-Csv new-test.csv -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation
```

the output:

```
"HEADER1"|"HEADER2"|"HEADER3"
"04.05 test & t, 04.06.01 test test, 04.10.02 test & t, 04.07.01 test test"|"test"|"TEST, TEST"
```

It is useful to use the `$obj.psobject.Properties` property to replace the values of all properties.

```
# import
$data = Import-Excel test.xlsx -StartRow 4

# replace the values of all properties
$data | ForEach-Object { $_.psobject.Properties } | Where-Object Value -is string |
ForEach-Object { $_.Value = $_.Value.Replace("`n",", ").Replace("&amp;", "&") }

# export
$data | Export-Csv new-test.csv -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to insert empty rows and columns, add them after converting by `ConvertTo-CSV`.

```
$data | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation | ForEach-Object { "" } { "|" + $_ } | Out-File new-test.csv
```

the output:

```
|"HEADER1"|"HEADER2"|"HEADER3"
|"04.05 test & t, 04.06.01 test test, 04.10.02 test & t, 04.07.01 test test"|"test"|"TEST, TEST"
```

If the headers are duplicated, the `-NoHeader` parameter is required. And remove the automatically attached headers before saving.

```
$data = Import-Excel test.xlsx -StartRow 4 -StartColumn 2 -NoHeader
$data | foreach { $_.psobject.Properties } | where Value -is string | foreach { $_.Value = $_.Value.Replace("`n",", ").Replace("&amp;", "&") }

$data | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File new-test.csv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @rokumaru for the answer and it works for this data but I need the parameter "NoHeader" because the excel file contains duplicate column names and then the above solution gives error to add parameter "NoHeader" or "HeaderName". Can we do something for this ? I will upload the test data file soon.

Comment: I have attached the sheet for reference. This requires "NoHeader" to import.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot but how do we remove the double quotes ? I tried "Encoding -UTF8" but does not help.

Comment: In that case, use the `-join` operator instead of `ConvertTo-CSV`.          `$data | foreach { $_.psobject.Properties.Value -join "|" } | Out-File new-test.csv`

Comment: Thanks. You are great !